# Split row and flip colum value

Tags: pyspark

How could I best stplit a single row into 2 and flip the values of the src_* to dest_* and dest_* to src_* for the second row?

```
|source_ip  |destination_ip|src_port|dst_port|
|192.168.0.1|10.0.0.1      |5000    |22      |
```

into

```
|ip         |src_port|dst_port|
|192.168.0.1|5000    |22      |
|10.0.0.1   |22      |5000    |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select `source_ip,src_port,dest_port` then union it with `dest_ip,**dst_port_src_port**`.

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([['192.168.0.1','10.0.0.1',5000,22]],['source_ip','destination_ip','src_port','dst_port'])
df2 = df.select(['source_ip','src_port','dst_port']).union(df.select(['destination_ip','dst_port','src_port']))
df2 = df2.withColumnRenamed("source_ip", "ip")
df2.show()
```

**Output:**

```
+-----------+--------+--------+
|         ip|src_port|dst_port|
+-----------+--------+--------+
|192.168.0.1|    5000|      22|
|   10.0.0.1|      22|    5000|
+-----------+--------+--------+
```

Folllowup: when you have n columns. all constant columns can be kept in a variable and the swap ones in another variable.

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([['1','xxx','192.168.0.1','10.0.0.1',5000,22]],['colno','somothercol','source_ip','destination_ip','src_port','dst_port'])
constant_columns = ['colno','somothercol']
swap_columns1 = ['source_ip','src_port','dst_port']
swap_columns2 = ['destination_ip','dst_port','src_port']
df2 = df.select([*constant_columns,*swap_columns1]).union(df.select([*constant_columns,*swap_columns2]))
df2 = df2.withColumnRenamed("source_ip", "ip")
df2.show()
```

**Output:**

```
+-----+-----------+-----------+--------+--------+
|colno|somothercol|         ip|src_port|dst_port|
+-----+-----------+-----------+--------+--------+
|    1|        xxx|192.168.0.1|    5000|      22|
|    1|        xxx|   10.0.0.1|      22|    5000|
+-----+-----------+-----------+--------+--------+
```

Comment: fantastic! is there an easy way to extend this. Lets say I have about 25 columns but I only have to swap 5 of them. The rest stays but needs to be part of the resulting df

Comment: @Chris Updated my answer take a look.

Comment: thanks. the output is not correct since not swapped in the followup

Comment: hi, I am getting invalid syntax. I am using v2.4.0

Comment: are you using python2?

Comment: It works fine on [2.4](https://databricks-prod-cloudfront.cloud.databricks.com/public/4027ec902e239c93eaaa8714f173bcfc/4404819181006222/3089931271256439/6042668295856651/latest.html)

Comment: I wonder if this can be optimized. It seems to run extremely long on very large datasets (5 bil. records)

Comment: hm I am not sure if anything can be done except from configs considering it;s just a union